# unable to set this.state variable in node/react simple input example

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

```
export default class extends Component {
constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = { searchTerm: ''}

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
      }

handleChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ searchTerm: event.target.value })
  console.log('event.target.value')
  console.log(event.target.value)
  console.log('this.searchTerm')
  console.log(this.searchTerm)
}

handleSubmit = () => {
  console.log('Button Clicked')
  console.log(this.searchTerm)
}

  render() {

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <label>
                Search:
                <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
              </label>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          )

  }

}
```

My issue is that the console is showing undefined for this.seachTerm value and the event.target.value is showing the correct output. Why is the state variable not being set? I have changed this answer using the same example from an answer below. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Is the class not setup correctly? This is a sub-component.

[image: Console Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.state.searchTerm` instead of `this.searchTerm` and you will be fine!

Comment: Damn newbie mistakes. THANK YOU!